# Loading different addresses in an iOS webView

Tags: ios, uiwebview

Hi I have an iOS app with 3 views: mapView, webView, and a standard homeView. What I want to know is: is there anyway I can load different address into the same webView depending on which button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the loadRequest: method of [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006950-CH3-SW16)

The following is a rough example:

```
-(void)buttonActionHandler1
{
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
}

-(void)buttonActionHandler2
{
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://adamatomic.com/canabalt/"]];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
}

-(void)buttonActionHandler3
{
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://http://www.wikipedia.org/"]];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
}
```